# Caliburn.Micro + MaterialToolkitDialog not Open .. : (

Tags: caliburn.micro

with [Calibrun.Micro(WPF)](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) + [MaterialToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit),
I tried to open Dialog. but not work..
[Could you check my code ? (in GitHub)](https://github.com/bidasknakayama/MaterialToolkitDialogCalibrunMicro)

Here is small test project.

Click the "Open" button.

[image]

this button fired dialog like this.

```
public async void NewConnection(){
  var result = await DialogHost.Show(
  new UserControl { DataContext = new TestDialogViewModel() },
  "MainDialogHost");           
}
```

Change to gray background( good ), but No dialog.. Why ?
[image]

Comment: To open as dialog you should consider using CMs [IWindowManager](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/wp71/WindowManager.cs)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

```
// MainViewModel.cs
TestDialogViewModel vm;
...
public async void NewConnection()
{

        vm = IoC.Get<TestDialogViewModel>();
        var dialog = new TestDialogView()
        {
            DataContext = vm
        };

        var result = await DialogHost.Show(dialog, "MainDialogHost",
            (object sender, DialogOpenedEventArgs eventArgs) =>
            {
                // pass DialogSession to ViewModel. 
                // View Model can close own dialog !
                vm.dialogSession = eventArgs.Session;
            },
            (object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs eventArgs) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"IPaddress = "+vm.IpAddress);                    
            });

    }
```

and

```
<!-- in MainView.xaml -->
<materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="MainDialogHost" 
                           CloseOnClickAway="True"
                           cal:Message.Attach="[Event DialogClosing]=[Action DialogHost_OnDialogClosing()]"
                          >
```

and..

```
   // in TestDialogViewModel
   public DialogSession dialogSession;        
    public void BtnConnect()
    {
        dialogSession.Close();
    }
```

and..

```
<!-- in TestDialogView.xaml -->
<StackPanel Margin="20" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock>Input IP Address</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="0 20 0 10" 
                 FontSize="28"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             Text="{Binding Path=IpAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                    cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action BtnConnect()]"
                        IsDefault="True"
                        Margin="0 8 8 0">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <system:Boolean xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">True</system:Boolean>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
                Connect
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Screenshots.

[image]

[image]

It will help someone Caliburn.Micro user !

: )